# ParseError at [row,col]:[18,9] Message: expected start or end tag i am getting this error while running

Tags: android, manifest

here is my manifest file  code i am getting this error"ParseError at [row,col]:[18,9] Message: expected start or end tag  i am getting this error while running"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".fare">
        android:windowsSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PoolActivity" />

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/map_key" />

    <activity android:name=".BottomNavigation" />
    <activity android:name=".Registration" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? how did you get there? what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the '>' at the end of the line, remove it.

```
 <activity android:name=".fare" >  // <-- Before
 <activity android:name=".fare"  // <-- After
```